# IPv4 Host ID, Network ID & Subnet ID by Example

Tags: subnet, ipv4

I just read this [amazing Serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/49836/252081) to a very basic question: How does IPv4 subnetting work? Although I follow most of everything that was stated in the accepted answer, I'm still drawing a big mental blank over the single most important concept described right near the very beginning: how the subnet bitmasking calculations work.

The example in that answer is an IP of `10.13.216.41/18`:

```
      10.      13.     216.      41
00001010.00001101.11011000.00101001 - IP address as bytes
```

Then the author provides this working area:

```
      10.      13.     216.      41
00001010.00001101.11011000.00101001 - IP address
11111111.11111111.11000000.00000000 - subnet mask (/18 => 255.255.192.0)
00001010.00001101.11000000.00000000 - Portion of IP address covered by 1's in subnet mask, remaining bits set to 0
00000000.00000000.00011000.00101001 - Portion of IP address covered by 0's in subnet mask, remaining bits set to 0
```

I understand how the 3rd line is generated: its the logical conjunction ("ANDing") of the bits in the IP with the bits in the subnet mask. This makes total sense to me. **By the way, what is this 3rd line (`00001010.00001101.11000000.00000000`): the Host ID, the Network ID or the Subnet ID?**

But the 4th line (`00000000.00000000.00011000.00101001`) is just not making any sense to me. I've read this answer several times and cannot figure out how it gets calculated/derived, and what it even represents/is useful for (Host ID, Network ID, Subnet ID?). Any ideas where this comes from?! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First – notice that the 4th line has the opposite result of line 3. Where the bitwise conjunction with the mask left the `1` bits untouched, line 4 has the opposite so it must have been the conjunction with the *opposite of the mask.*

So if line 3 was `address AND mask`, line 4 is `address AND (NOT mask)`.

What both lines mean is answered below.

---

Second – forget about "subnet ID". That was a separate number back when you had classful networks with subnets. In modern-day networking it is *no longer separate* from "network ID".

That simplifies things a bit, since now you only have two states: if it's covered by 1-bits in the mask, it's the network part; if it's covered by 0-bits, then it's the host part.

In addition, CIDR requires subnet mask bits to be contiguous, so it gets even simpler: **`/18` means the first 18 bits** from the left are network ID, everything else (i.e. 14 remaining bits) are host ID.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, you can still calculate a "subnet ID" when dividing a larger network into smaller ones – it is much more noticeable in IPv6, where it's customary to allocate /48's to sites and use /64-sized subnets, resulting in a very neat division.

However, while early IPv6 revisions had *temporarily* revived a formal address structure (you had "top-level aggregations" and so on), that's again no longer a thing and any "subnet IDs" are purely your own decision.

Comment: Thanks @grawity (+1) - what do the 3rd and 4th lines represent? How are they used, or how are they useful?

Comment: The network ID with no host bits is used to describe the whole network (e.g. `10.13.192.0/18` in this case). The host ID with no network bits is, in practice, useless.

Comment: Ahhhhh, the "Network ID" *identifies the network*...doh! So `10.13.192.0` is a `/18` subnet with a range of 16,382 possible hosts "inside" of it. Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: (Although in IPv6, hosts usually make up their own host ID and combine it with network prefix when deriving their full address, but I don't remember any case where it would be useful to do the opposite. If you have the full address, you almost never need to extract the host ID from it.)

Comment: Yes, that interpretation is right. (Although e.g. routing tables only care about the 'network' bits, it is much clearer to _humans_ when the network is always named the same way, i.e. with all host bits zeroed.)